# VB Login Form doesn't proceed

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I can't get my VB login form to proceed.

```
Public Class form_login



Private Function AuthenticateUser() As Boolean
    Dim username As String = txtbok_login_username.Text
    Dim password As String = txtbox_login_password.Text
    Dim domain As String = "patten.local"

    Dim isAuthenticated As Boolean = ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(domain, username, password, "Admins@WokasCustomer.com")

    Return isAuthenticated
End Function




Public Function ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(ByVal domainName As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal userPassword As String, ByVal groupName As String) As Boolean
    Dim isValidated As Boolean = False

    Try

        Dim ldapPath As String = "LDAP://patten.local"
        Dim dirEntry As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, userName, userPassword, DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
        Dim dirSearcher As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)



        dirSearcher.Filter = "(userPrincipalName=" & userName & ")"
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")

        Dim result As DirectoryServices.SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()

        If Not result Is Nothing Then

            If groupName.Length = 0 Then
                isValidated = True
            Else
                Dim groupCount As Integer = result.Properties("Fiserv Processing - MIS").Count
                Dim isInGroup As Boolean = False

                For index As Integer = 0 To groupCount - 1
                    Dim groupDN As String = result.Properties("Fiserv Processing - MIS").Item(index)

                    Dim equalsIndex As Integer = groupDN.IndexOf("=")
                    Dim commaIndex As Integer = groupDN.IndexOf(",")

                    Dim group As String = groupDN.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1).ToLower
                    If group.Equals(groupName.ToLower) Then
                        isInGroup = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next index

                isValidated = isInGroup
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return isValidated

End Function
```

What am I missing in my code?

I'm trying to authenticate a user to an active directory group.  Once I enter my username and password on the login form and click ok, the form just sits without proceeding.  Am I missing post procedure code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we looked at the same guide somewhere on the internet... Here's what I implemented in my solution a while back and it's working without issue:

```
Private Function ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean

    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    Dim Entry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & Domain, Username, Password)
    Dim Searcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry)
    Searcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.OneLevel

    Try
        Dim Results As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne
        Success = Not (Results Is Nothing)
    Catch
        Success = False
    End Try

    Return Success
End Function
```

Here is how I called the function:

```
If ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName, passBox.Text) Then
   ' Success, you can proceed
   ' continueDoingSomething()
Else
   ' Failure, go do something else
   ' failedLogin()
End If
```